# Реализация метода с аргументом через интерфейс

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Я хочу реализовать интерфейс `IUpdateable` который содержит метод `Update`. Суть метода в том, что он принимает 1 аргумент и присваивает свойства этого объекта  "this-объекту". Пример реализации:

```
 public interface IUpdateable
 {
     public void Update() { }
 }


 public class ClientCompany : ICloneable, IClient, IUpdateable
 {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NameCompany Name { get; set; } = new NameCompany();
    public AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; } = new AddressesMultiple();
    public PropsCompany Props { get; set; } = new PropsCompany();
    public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; } = new BankInfo();

    public void IUpdateable.Update(ClientCompany item)
    {
        Name = item.Name;
        Address = item.Address;
        Props = item.Props;
        BankInfo = item.BankInfo;
    }
}

public class ClientPerson : ICloneable, IClient, IUpdateable 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NamePerson Name { get; set; } = new NamePerson();
    public AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; } = new AddressesMultiple();
    public PropsPerson Props { get; set; } = new PropsPerson();
    public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; } = new BankInfo();
    public List<LegalCase> Cases { get; set; } = new List<LegalCase>();

    public void Update(ClientPerson item)
    {
        Name = item.Name;
        Address = item.Address;
        Props = item.Props;
        BankInfo = item.BankInfo;
    }
}
```

**В чем проблема:**

Возникает исключение, поскольку у метода Update в интерфейсе 0 аргументов, хотя предполагается 1 аргумент:

```
    public void EditClient<T>(T Client) where T : IUpdateable, IClient
    {
        //Создаем клон объекта
        T editedClient = (T)Client.Clone();
        //Создаем диалоговое окно и передаем в него ссылку на клон
        WindowEditClient windowEditClient = new WindowEditClient(editedClient);
        windowEditClient.ShowDialog();

        //Если изменения прошли - вызываем метод Update
        if (windowEditClient.DialogResult == true)
        {
            //ОШИБКА: Метод Update не содержит перегрузок, которые принимают 1 аргумент.
            Client.Update(editedClient);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Если изменить метод в интерфейсе так чтобы он принимал 1 аргумент, то код компилируется без ошибок, но не работает. Дебаг показывает что C# теперь считает метод Update в интерфейсе полноценно реализованным методом и обращается к нему, а поскольку реализации там нет, то ничего не происходит.

```
public interface IUpdateable : ICloneable
{
    public void Update(IUpdateable Item) 
    { // Код исполняется здесь
    }
}

public class ClientCompany : ICloneable, IClient, IUpdateable
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NameCompany Name { get; set; } = new NameCompany();
    public AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; } = new AddressesMultiple();
    public PropsCompany Props { get; set; } = new PropsCompany();
    public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; } = new BankInfo();

    public void Update(ClientCompany item)
    {
        // Код здесь не исполняется
        Name = item.Name;
        Address = item.Address;
        Props = item.Props;
        BankInfo = item.BankInfo;
    }
}
```

Правка: Добавил имплементацию IClient

```
public interface IClient
{
    public List<LegalCase> Cases { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас есть 2 метода update в классах?

Comment: А разве в описании интерфейса могут быть тела методов? Вообще-то IDE должна ошибку выдавать в этом случае. В интерфейсе не может быть реализаций.

Comment: Верно, один в классе `ClientCompany` другой в классе `ClientPerson` и я хотел бы чтобы они реализовывали 1 интерфейс

Comment: `public interface IUpdateable
 {
     public void Update() { }
 }` - здесь ошибку должно выдавать вообще-то. Должно принимать только `public void Update();`

Comment: @CrazyElf Начиная с C# 8.0 как я понимаю интерфейсы могут содержать дефолтные имплементации методов, но мне как раз не нужна дефолтная имплементация. Мне нужен интерфейс, который содержит метод с параметром.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov Не знал. Ну ок, а объект какого типа вы передаёте методу `Update` во второй версии кода? Может он по типу аргумента выбирает реализацию, если их две с разным типом аргумента? Может он тут не понимает, что это перегрузка интерфейса, поскольку тип аргумента разный.

Comment: @CrazyElf Вообще объект должен быть того же типа, что и объект реализующий интерфейс, т.к. происходит присваивание значений  от первого ко второму. Т.е. объект ClientCompany содержит метод Update принимающий аргумент ClientCompany и.т.д. Во втором варианте когда я в интерфейсе прописал аргумет типа IUpdateable, т.к. объект реализующий его тоже его реализовывает по определению.

Comment: Ваши классы `ClientCompany` и `ClientPerson` слишком разные. У них лишь два свойства совпадают: `AddressesMultiple Address` и `BankInfo BankInfo`. Поэтому невозможно напрямую реализовать то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Покажите определение интерфейса `IClient`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Удалось разобраться? если да, то отметьте наиболее полезный ответ принятым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в определении интерфейса вы указали модификатор `public` и тело метода `{ }` - в данном случае пустое, - значит это [метод интерфейса по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-methods).

```
public void Update() { }
```

---

Вам, очевидно, нужен примерно следующий интерфейс:

```
public interface IUpdateable
{
    void Update(ICommon item);
}
```

Где `ICommon` - интерфейс, содержащий общие свойства. (Я думал, `IClient` как раз содержит их.)

Вот определение этого интерфейса:

```
public interface ICommon
{
    AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; }
    BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь можно написать такой код:

```
public class ClientCompany : ICommon, IUpdateable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; } = new AddressesMultiple();
    public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; } = new BankInfo();

    // остальные свойства

    public void Update(ICommon item)
    {
        Address = item.Address;
        BankInfo = item.BankInfo;
    }
}

public class ClientPerson : ICommon, IUpdateable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; } = new AddressesMultiple();
    public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; } = new BankInfo();

    // остальные свойства

    public void Update(ICommon item)
    {
        Address = item.Address;
        BankInfo = item.BankInfo;
    }
}
```

Реализация может быть явной: `void IUpdateable.Update(ICommon item)`.

Остальные свойства у этих классов разные, поэтому обновлять их таким способом не получится.

---

Можно использовать обобщённые типы (generics).

```
public interface IUpdateable<T>
{
    void Update(T item);
}

public class ClientCompany : IUpdateable<ClientCompany>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NameCompany Name { get; set; } = new NameCompany();
    public AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; } = new AddressesMultiple();
    public PropsCompany Props { get; set; } = new PropsCompany();
    public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; } = new BankInfo();

    public void Update(ClientCompany item)
    {
        Name = item.Name;
        Address = item.Address;
        Props = item.Props;
        BankInfo = item.BankInfo;
    }
}

public class ClientPerson : IUpdateable<ClientPerson>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NamePerson Name { get; set; } = new NamePerson();
    public AddressesMultiple Address { get; set; } = new AddressesMultiple();
    public PropsPerson Props { get; set; } = new PropsPerson();
    public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; } = new BankInfo();
    public List<LegalCase> Cases { get; set; } = new List<LegalCase>();

    public void Update(ClientPerson item)
    {
        Name = item.Name;
        Address = item.Address;
        Props = item.Props;
        BankInfo = item.BankInfo;
    }
}
```

Но в этом случае уже не получится, например, создать коллекцию наподобие `List<IUpdateable>`, в которую можно поместить классы обоих типов. И, соответственно, не будет работать ваш метод `EditClient`: в нем нельзя будет вызвать  `client.Update(editedClient);`

---

Последняя итерация рефакторинга.

```
public interface IUpdateable
{
    void Update(IUpdateable item);
}

public class ClientCompany : IUpdateable
{
    // свойства опущены

    public void Update(IUpdateable item)
    {
        ClientCompany client = (ClientCompany)item;
        Name = client.Name;
        Address = client.Address;
        Props = client.Props;
        BankInfo = client.BankInfo;
    }
}

public class ClientPerson : IUpdateable
{
    // свойства опущены

    public void Update(IUpdateable item)
    {
        ClientPerson client = (ClientPerson)item;
        Name = client.Name;
        Address = client.Address;
        Props = client.Props;
        BankInfo = client.BankInfo;
    }
}
```

Выглядит, честно говоря, криво. Но `EditClient` должен работать (не проверял).